# Branches separated after old commit edit

Tags: git

I created a new branch and started working on it

```
Z--A--B--C (master)
          \-D--E (new-branch)
```

Then I rebased to edit an old commit (`A`) while still on `new-branch` and my branches got separated

```
Z--A--B--C (master)
 \-A*--B--C--D--E (new-branch) (A* -> edited commit)
```

How can I fuse them back to the following state?

```
Z--A*--B--C (master)
           \-D--E (new-branch)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what you have post-rebase is this (I'll spell them `B'` etc rather than `B*` etc, since that seems to be the more usual way of writing these):

```
Z - A - B - C   <-- master
  \
    A'- B'- C'- D'- E'  <-- new-branch
```

This is because rebase has to *copy* each old commit (or more precisely, copy most of it, except for the changed bits) to change anything in it, and after modifying commit `A` to make `A'`, it must copy and modify `B` because the new `B'` is different: `B'` has `A'` as its parent, rather than `A`.  (Everything else is the same, but changing the parent requires making a whole new commit.  Fortunately commits are pretty tiny.  They just have the parents, timestamps and such, commit-message, and one SHA-1 for the "tree" associated with the commit, and git can re-use the old tree.)

If you want to keep `A'` the way it is now *and* have it appear in the history for `master`, you'll have to re-point the `master` label at commit `C'`.  This will "abandon" commit `C`<sup>1</sup> (and the ASCII art here is now uncomfortably crowded :-) ):

```
Z - A - B - C       [abandoned]
  \           .---------- master
    A'- B'- C'- D'- E'  <-- new-branch
```

This also means that anyone else who had earlier seen you "publish" (or "advertise") that your `master` meant whatever SHA-1 commit `C` has, will see you as having "rewritten history": commit `C` is no longer in the picture at all, nor `B` nor `A`.  Instead, now `master` points to `C'`, which points to `B'`, which points to `A'`, which points back to `Z`.

Of course, the same is true for `new-branch`: it used to point to `E` but now it points to `E'` instead.

On the other hand, maybe you don't really want to change `master`.  In that case, you have just two options: giving up on `A'` entirely, or having `master` and `new-branch` diverge after commit `Z`.

Let's go over each as a group (except the last option, that's easy: do nothing, that's what you have now!).

---

To re-point `master`, there are two easy(ish) ways:

- Get on the branch, and then use `git reset`, which (in most of its operational modes) will change the commit to which the branch points:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git reset --hard new-branch~2  # point master to commit C'
  ```

  (As always with `git reset --hard`, be very careful before running it, that you are on the branch you want to re-set, and have no un-saved in-work-tree data.)
- While *not* on the branch, use `git branch -f` to forcibly move it:

  ```
  git branch -f master new-branch~2 # point master to commit C'
  ```

---

If you don't want to move `master` and do want to give up `A'` and restore the old `new-branch`, there are a number of ways.  Assuming you're on it now and have not done anything since the rebase, the special ref-name `ORIG_HEAD`<sup>2</sup> will point to the original commit `E`.  In other words, we can draw a more complete picture of the original post-rebase situation like this:

```
                D - E   <-- ORIG_HEAD (copied from new-branch before rebase)
              /
Z - A - B - C           <-- master
  \
    A'- B'- C'- D'- E'  <-- new-branch
```

So:

- If you're on `new-branch` and want to un-do your rebase, `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD` will do the trick.  (Use the same care with `--hard` as usual.)
- If it's too late for that, you can find commit `E` in your reflogs, and `git reset --hard` to the raw SHA-1, or using a reflog spelling like `new-branch@{yesterday}` or `HEAD@{3}` or whatever.
- If you don't mind copying `D'` and `E'` to yet-new-copies, `D''` and `E''`, you can re-rebase `new-branch` with a longer form of rebase using `--onto` (which I see is in [Magnus Bäck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21715576/1256452), that got in before this one).

---

<sup>1</sup>The reflog will preserve commit `C` for a while, so the repo will retain the commit until the reflog entry expires.  So it's not *completely* abandoned, or at least, not yet.

<sup>2</sup>This `ORIG_HEAD` "special" reference is set when you start a new rebase, but also by things like `git merge`.  You can use `git log ORIG_HEAD` or similar to see where it actually points, if you're not sure.

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer, I finally did `git reset --hard new-branch~2`

Answer (score 2):

Your actual state after the bad rebase is this:

```
Z--A--B--C (master)
 \-A*--B*--C*--D*--E* (new-branch)
```

Now, you could use the reflog to restore the previous state of new-branch, check out the correct branch, and do the rebase. On the other hand, you'll end up with the same state of forked branches so...

You'll have to rebase new-branch. It's quite possibly as simple as this:

```
git rebase master
```

Git will automatically skip applying commits B* and C* since they'll probably end up empty (unless commit A touched code that they also touched, in which case you'll get a conflict). If you want to make sure to *only* rebase commit D* and E*, restrict which commits are subject to the rebase and use `--onto`:

```
git rebase --onto master HEAD~2
```

HEAD~2 means C* and represents the boundary of the rebase operation, i.e. we'll be selecting D* and E* and apply them onto master.